# Restrict respond_to to JSON only, rails 2.xx

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to restrict `respond_to` to JSON only, because I am constructing a web service that will provide JSON formatted output only.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `before_filter`, defined in the `ApplicationController` which would check the `request.format` for JSON and then respond with an appropriate 4xx HTTP error code and message if not matched.

If to enforce this for all controllers the invoke the filter in the `ApplicationController`, otherwise invoke it in the selected controllers of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer bjg (you answered my question again!!)
Which status code is more acceptable: 406 / 415?

406: Content-type requested in the `accept` header is not supported,

or

415: Server cannot interpret the content part of the HTTP request?

Comment: The choice of 4xx might be another good question to ask. I really am not sure what is appropriate. I don't know whether this is something that is considered application context specific or whether there are recognized conventions.

Comment: Related question about status codes:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294483/http-406-and-415-error-codes