# Spring MVC + Jquery Ajax shows 406 error?

Tags: java, json, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I have searched a lot and cant find a solution.Similar threads are also in our stack overflow.But no use.So I have created a new thread.

My JSP is ,

```
<boby>
<% System.out.println("request.getContextPath() : "+request.getContextPath()); %>
<h1>Spring_JsonTest Example</h1>
    <table>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><div id="error" class="error"></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Enter your name : </td><td> <input type="text" id="name"><br/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Your Education : </td><td> <input type="text" id="education"><br/></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add Users" onclick="doAjaxPost()"><br/></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><div id="info" class="success"></div></td></tr>
    </table>    
</body>
```

My Jquery is ,

```
function doAjaxPost() {  
      // get the form values  
      var name = $('#name').val();
      var education = $('#education').val();

      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: contexPath + "/AddUser.html",  
        data: "name=" + name + "&education=" + education,
        success: function(response){
          // we have the response 
          if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
          userInfo = "<ol>";
          for( i =0 ; i < response.result.length ; i++){
              userInfo += "<br><li><b>Name</b> : " + response.result[i].name + 
              ";<b> Education</b> : " + response.result[i].education;
          }
          userInfo += "</ol>";
          $('#info').html("User has been added to the list successfully. " + userInfo);
          $('#name').val('');
              $('#education').val('');
              $('#error').hide('slow');
              $('#info').show('slow');
          }else{
          errorInfo = "";
          alert("Success response : "+response)
          for( i =0 ; i < response.result.length ; i++){
              errorInfo += "<br>" + (i + 1) +". " + response.result[i].code;
          }
          $('#error').html("Please correct following errors: " + errorInfo);
          $('#info').hide('slow');
          $('#error').show('slow');
          }       
        },  
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            alert("status :"+xhr.status+"\nthrownError : "+thrownError+"\nresponseText : "+xhr.responseText);
            alert('Error: ' +xhr.description);  
        } 
      });  
    }
```

My Controller is ,

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>(); 

    @RequestMapping(value="/AddUser.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody JsonResponse addUser(@ModelAttribute(value="user") User user, BindingResult result ){
        System.out.println("Add user POST method");
        JsonResponse res = new JsonResponse();
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(result, "name", "Name can not be empty.");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(result, "education", "Education not be empty");
        if(!result.hasErrors()){
            userList.add(user);
            res.setStatus("SUCCESS");
            res.setResult(userList);
        }else{
            res.setStatus("FAIL");
            res.setResult(result.getAllErrors());
        }

        return res;
    }

}
```

My JsonResponse.java is,

```
package com.tps.jsonTest.service;

public class JsonResponse {
    private String status = null;
    private Object result = null;
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public Object getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(Object result) {
        System.out.println("Result : "+result.toString());
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

and My User.java is,

```
package com.tps.jsonTest.service;

public class User {

    private String name = null;
    private String education = null;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEducation() {
        return education;
    }
    public void setEducation(String education) {
        this.education = education;
    }

}
```

In my console,

```
Add user POST method
Name : Anand
Education : B.E
Result : [com.tps.jsonTest.service.User@df2940]
```

Jar files I have used are,

```
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.12.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.12.jar
log4j-1.2.9.jar
servlet-api-2.4.jar
spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
```

In my browser the error would be,

[image]

I cant parse the object using jquery and it moves on the error.Hope our stack users will help me.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Can you post that error in the image? It's hard to read...

Comment: @Thihara `Status:406`,`Thrown error : undefined`.

Comment: can you try setting the content type to text/json

Comment: did u mean `dataType: 'json'` ?

Comment: This will help, Using firebug, can you check the HTTP headers for the ajax request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294483/http-406-and-415-error-codes

Comment: @sathya did u mean dataType: 'json' ?

Comment: It looks like your java and jsp codes are ok and included the required jars. dataType:'json' is not required, see the docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Try a clean build

Comment: Any more suggestions from any one ?

Comment: hmmm...Once I solved this by replace jackson with jackson2...I didn't know why but it just worked. And make sure you have < mvc:annotation-driven /> in your web application context.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem in Spring 3.2.2 or 3.2.3 or 3.2.4. I have tried the same example in Spring 3.0.0 and Spring 3.1.4 it is working fine. So change the spring jars and give a try.

Regards
Madhu

Comment: Yep - I was downloading files with no trouble at all until I tried upgrading from 3.1.4 to 4.0.0. Downgrading to 3.2.0 also failed. I'm going to try to work out whether there's something else which needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I am using Spring 3.2 with UrlBasedViewResolver.

For all ajax calls it was giving 406. I tried changing headers, dataType all above solutions but nothing worked. Then I found jackson jars are missing.
I added below 2 jars and it started working fine for me.

jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.4.jar

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the content-type of the response is not acceptable to the request.

Your ajax call does not specify the `dataType`, so jQuery infers based on the url extension that the response should be of content type `text/html`, but your server does not know how to convert a pojo into an html!

The solution should be to simply add `dataType='json'` to your ajax call.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since your doing a `POST`, then your data should not be in query string format. Pass a json object for the `data` parameter instead.

```
data:{name: name, 
      education: education}
```

Comment: There is no restriction that you cannot pass url params for POST requests.