# HTTP Status 406. Spring MVC 3.2, jQuery, JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring

I am trying to get the JSON reponse from a jquery Ajax call in a spring mvc application. The request seems to fine as I see the debug statements in the controller method. However, I keep seeing the HTTP 406 error (**GET http://:8080/SampleFormEventInSpring/getData.html 406 Not Acceptable**). My setup is given below. Any help is highly appreciated

```
Spring 3.2
jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.4.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.7.4
Eclispe Juno Service Release 2
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
```

**Response Headers**

```
Content-Language    en
  Content-Length    1067
    Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
            Date    Sun, 05 Oct 2014 01:06:16 GMT
          Server    Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

**Request Headers**

```
          Accept    application/json
 Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language    en-US,en;q=0.5
          Cookie    JSESSIONID=31E855326C016B194B0F013FEC470FAD
            Host    localhost:8080
         Referer    http://localhost:8080/SampleFormEventInSpring/event.html
      User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Controller Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Data> getProviderList() {
    System.out.println("Inside EventController.getData Begin");

    List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();

    Data pData = new Data();
    pData.setId("0012M");
    pData.setName("Group");
    dataList.add(pData);

    pData = new Data();
    pData.setId("12345");
    pData.setName("Individual");
    dataList.add(pData);

    for(Data iPdata : dataList) {
        System.out.println("pID : " + iPdata.getId() + ",pNAME : " + iPdata.getName());
    }

    System.out.println("Inside EventController.getData End");
    return dataList;
}
```

Data.java

```
public class Data {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#getData").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
                url:'getData.html',
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data){
                    alert("Success");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem

From your **jQuery** and **@RequestMapping** about the URL to be used, edit

from

- `getData.html`

to

- `getData`

Yes, remove the `.html` extension.

Furthermore: You have `url:'getData.html',` and `@RequestMapping(value = "/getData"`
They does not match.

Change from

- `url:'getData.html'

to

- `url:'getData'

Comment: Jordan, In the web.xml, the DispatcherServlet URL is mapped to *.html. Hence the URL is used as getData.html. Looks like the ajax request is entering the Controller method as I can see the debug statements. Not sure how to set the content type of the response to be of json type.

Comment: I work with Java Config, so no web.xml used, but I must do the same configuration, I have `dispatcher.addMapping("/");` so change `*.html` to `/`. I use in my URL `.htm`, so there is no problem with `/`. and with that and with a special `@Bean` I am able to work with .json and .xml without problems. Try it…

Comment: Thanks Jordan. It worked this time. Looks like when you have spring mvc application where a controller method is returning a JSON response, the dispatchservlet mapping needs to be set to just '/'.

Comment: Not really, I had the problem in the inverse order, I have tried to send json data (POST) through Ajax, and the URL has `.htm`, always failing, until I thought, what happens if I remove the `.htm` from the URL and then all work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget your response headers:

```
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
```

Should be:

```
Content-Type    application/json
```

Comment: I am already annotating the return object with @ResponseBody, using "<mvc:annotation-driven />" directive in my servlet.xml and then using the Jackson Jar in the classpath. I thought these should sufficient for setting the response body to be in json. In addition to these do I need to set the content type of the response header in my controller method?

Comment: Yes you need to set the content type to this so jQuery see's it, not only your internal app. Certain browsers may .give unexpected results if you don't set this.

Comment: I tried adding the content type by adding produces="application/json" in the @RequestMapping directive, however I stil get the http 406 error. Also, when I added this entry, the request is not going into the controller method

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923473/spring-mvc-jquery-ajax-shows-406-error

Answer (score 0):

Add the header to the request mapping headers = { "application/json" }

It should look like:

Controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = { "application/json" })
@ResponseBody
public List<Data> getProviderList() {
    System.out.println("Inside EventController.getData Begin");
...
```

The jQuery code looks fine, but see Manuel Jordan answer, he's right you are mapping to getData and not getData.**html**.

So make sure that your dispatcher servlet is mapped in web.xml to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or define and additional suffix for rest reqest e.g. ".json"

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and change the mapping accordingly.

I have a similar project in github https://github.com/ramanh3/rest-json maybe it can help.

Comment: When I add the headers = { "application/json" } directive I am getting http 404 error for the ajax url. However when I user headers = { "*/*" }, the request reaches the Controller method as I can see my debug statements. Not sure how to set the content type of the response to be of json type