# Specify allowed content types when anwering with HTTP 415

Tags: web-services, rest, http, http-headers

I'm looking into adding (more) precise responses to REST API client (4xx) errors. The direction seems quite clear, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294483/http-406-and-415-error-codes):

> 406 [sic] when you can't send what they want, 415 when they send what you don't want.

The difference seems to be that you can include allowed methods via the [Allow](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.7) header:

```
< PUT /api/articles/
> HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
> Allow: POST
```

But there isn't any equivalent response header for:

```
< POST /api/images/
< Content-Type: text/html
> HTTP 415 Unsuported media
```

The way I see it, I have the following options:

1. Sending [Accept](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) which is exactly for this, but a request-only header
2. Sending [Warning](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.46) which doesn't seem right at all.

Did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proposal:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wilde-accept-post-02

might be of interest.

Comment: So if I'm using POST and PATCH, I should be returning Accept-Post and [Accept-Patch](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789#section-3.1)?

Comment: You should read the draft and provide feedback to the authors. After all, it's just a draft right now.